# Adding/appending keys to JSON structure in python

Tags: python, json

Running Python 3.6 without supporting additional modules. I would like to append/add new entries to the "polygon" section. Any suggestions how:

JSON Structure:

```
{
   "messageId":775,
   "value":{
      "dataFrames":[
         {
            "content":{
               "workZone":[
                  {
                     "item":{
                        "text":"Test"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "item":{
                        "itis":333
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            "duratonTime":24,
            "frameType":"road Signage",
            "msgId":{
               "roadSignID":{
                  "mutcdCode":"warning",
                  "position":{
                     "elevation":634.0,
                     "lat":30.2,
                     "long":-80.5
                  },
                  "viewAngle":"111111"
               }
            },
            "priority":1,
            "regions":[
               {
                  "anchor":{
                     "elevation":634.0,
                     "lat":34.3,
                     "long":-80.5
                  },
                  "description":{
                     "geometry":{
                        "direction":"0000",
                        "laneWidth":5.123,
                        "polygon":[
                           [
                              
                           ]
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "directionality":"forward"
               }
            ],
            "sspLocationRights":1,
            "sspMsgRights1":0,
            "sspMsgRights2":0,
            "sspTimRights":1,
            "startTime":1599041581.5259035,
            "startYear":2020
         }
      ],
      "msgCnt":0,
      "packetID":775,
      "source":"XX"
   }
}
```

I tried to form a JSON and adding a String for the polygon but it is being added with quotes. So not sure if the best way is to access the polygon section and add new entries.

Expected JSON:

```
{
   "messageId":775,
   "value":{
      "msgCnt":0,
      "packetID":775,
      "source":"C-V2X",
      "dataFrames":[
         {
            "sspTimRights":1,
            "frameType":"road Signage",
            "msgId":{
               "roadSignID":{
                  "position":{
                     "lat":-80.38466909433639,
                     "long":37.17942971412366,
                     "elevation":634.0
                  },
                  "viewAngle":"1000000000000000",
                  "mutcdCode":"warning"
               }
            },
            "startYear":2020,
            "startTime":1598992048.1489706,
            "duratonTime":24,
            "priority":1,
            "sspLocationRights":1,
            "regions":[
               {
                  "anchor":{
                     "lat":-80.38466909433639,
                     "long":37.17942971412366,
                     "elevation":634.0
                  },
                  "directionality":"forward",
                  "description":{
                     "geometry":{
                        "direction":"1000000000000000",
                        "laneWidth":5.123,
                        "polygon":[
                           [
                              [
                                 37.17942971412366,
                                 -80.38466909433639
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.179543821887314,
                                 -80.38487318094833
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.17967679727881,
                                 -80.38510713731363
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.17995588265411,
                                 -80.38560355518067
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.17998272884397,
                                 -80.38557977915941
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.179703594552834,
                                 -80.38508327461031
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.17957064376986,
                                 -80.38484936187977
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.17945660930624,
                                 -80.38464540586482
                              ],
                              [
                                 37.17942971412366,
                                 -80.38466909433639
                              ]
                           ]
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ],
            "sspMsgRights1":0,
            "sspMsgRights2":0,
            "content":{
               "workZone":[
                  {
                     "item":{
                        "text":"Buffer Area"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "item":{
                        "itis":775
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: What entries do you want to append? Please give an example on how the result should look like.

Comment: @Gledi. I added the expected JSON. When I tried to add the content/entries inside the polygon from another string, quotes are added and I tried the strip() without success

Comment: The problem is that the entries in polygon should not be Strings but List of float numbers. In this case, you are probably adding the String: "[37.17942971412366, -80.38466909433639]" and not the List. Try running print(type(<the element you are trying to add>)) and tell me what you get.

Comment: @Gledi. Correct. I am adding string. Output is the following:
[37.17942971412366, -80.38466909433639],[37.179543821887314, -80.38487318094833],[37.17967679727881, -80.38510713731363],[37.17995588265411, -80.38560355518067],[37.17998272884397, -80.38557977915941],[37.179703594552834, -80.38508327461031],[37.17957064376986, -80.38484936187977],[37.17945660930624, -80.38464540586482],[37.17942971412366, -80.38466909433639]

So I need to add those entries to a List which can be added to the JSON?

Comment: Exactly. You need to parse the float numbers inside your string and then add them to a list. Than add this list to the polygon.
Repeat it for every entry you want to add into polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gledi suggested. Doing a List is the proper way to insert the "polygon" information into the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` points to the dict in the question - the code below should work.

```
data['value']['dataFrames'][0]['regions'][0]['description']['geometry']['polygon'][0].append('something')
```